# C# pathping process freeze

Tags: c#, process, visual-studio-2015, deadlock

I'm creating a network diagnostic application and trying to add a pathping command to it where it takes an adress from a textfield as path to ping when I press a button, but the application freezes when I press the button and nothing shows in the output window.

```
private void btn_PingPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo PathPingStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

    PathPingStartInfo.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
    PathPingStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    PathPingStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    PathPingStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    PathPingStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    PathPingStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    PathPingStartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);

    Process PathPing = new Process();

    PathPing.StartInfo = PathPingStartInfo;
    PathPing.Start();
    PathPing.StandardInput.WriteLine("PATHPING " + txt_PingPath.Text);

    while (PathPing.StandardOutput.Peek() > -1)
    {
        txt_Output.Text = PathPing.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    }
    while (PathPing.StandardError.Peek() > -1)
    {
        txt_Output.Text = PathPing.StandardError.ReadLine();
    }
    //txt_Output.Text = PathPing.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    PathPing.WaitForExit();
}
```

**EDIT**

I found the `while loop` from another question but it did not help. I still get no output in the output text window and the application still freezes.

Comment: would expect this `PathPing.WaitForExit();` to not be the last line in your code.. looks like your logic is off

Comment: @MethodMan Can you explain why it looks like my logic is off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PATHPING` command can end up running for several minutes before exiting, so your last line, `PathPing.WaitForExit();` will also not return for several minutes (or until pathping exits). You can't wait like this on the UI thread, because the UI also needs to use this thread to re-draw and listen for windows messages.

You can free up the UI thread so that your application doesnt freeze by either creating a new thread, or using async/await features in .Net 4.5+, or using the event pattern. The following example uses the event pattern.

```
private void btn_PingPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo PathPingStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

    PathPingStartInfo.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
    PathPingStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    PathPingStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    PathPingStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    PathPingStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    PathPingStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    PathPingStartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);

    Process PathPing = new Process();

    PathPing.StartInfo = PathPingStartInfo;
    PathPing.Start();
    PathPing.StandardInput.WriteLine("PATHPING " + txt_PingPath.Text);
    PathPing.StandardInput.Flush();

    PathPing.OutputDataReceived += (o, args) => txt_Output.Text += args.Data;
    PathPing.ErrorDataReceived += (o, args) => txt_Output.Text += args.Data;

    PathPing.BeginErrorReadLine();
    PathPing.BeginOutputReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This throws a `'System.InvalidOperationException'` in `System.Windows.Forms.dll` telling me that cross-thread operation not valid: `Control 'txt_Output' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`?

Comment: that error is because you're trying to access a UI object (in this case the txt_Outpu) from a different thread than the one on which it was created. you need to call `txt_Output.Invoke(...)` to switch context back on to the UI thread. It seems apparent to me by your question and comment here that you don't really understand how threads work - I'd recommend doing some research yourself, it will save you a lot of headache and all of these questions have been already asked before on SOF.